# AWS-SES Email address is not verified. Gmail account

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I have try to send email using `AWS-SES` when new customer registration.

But i got some error like this

> Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: mathuk22@gmail.com (Request ID: 2278b8eb-544e-11e9-bab8-536962476bb7)
>
> Note: Am not verify `mathuk22@gmail.com` email id in my `AWS-SES`

Without verify email how can i send email ?

```
exports.emailSend = (req, res) =>{
  var htmlContentData = req.body.htmlContentData; // html content
  var htmlSubjectData = req.body.htmlSubjectData; // subject
  var params = {
    Destination: {
      //BccAddresses: [], 
      //CcAddresses: [],
      ToAddresses: ["mathuk22@gmail.com"]
    },   
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Charset: "UTF-8",
          Data: htmlContentData // html mail content         
        },
        Text: {
          Charset: "UTF-8",
          Data: "Hello Charith Sample description time 1517831318946"
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: "UTF-8",
        Data: htmlSubjectData // html mail subject 
      }
    },
    ReplyToAddresses: [], 
    Source: "source@example.com",
  };
  ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) 
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    else
      res.send(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Initially AWS puts your account in Sandbox where you need to verify the recipient email address, you need to contact AWS Support and ask them to move your Account to production, once account is in production and limits have been increased, you don't need to verify recipient "To" address. It doesn't cause additional cost.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Answer (score -1):

[Do the following steps to verify email on AWS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6suD.png)